# How do I fix a bad commercial deb package?

Tags: debian, citrix, deb

The Citrix ICA Client (Receiver) 13 `.deb` package has some known issues.  How do I make changes to the package?  I need to remove some dependencies and change the install script.

Ref: [How do I install Citrix ICA Client (Receiver) 13 on Debian 64-bit Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/714375/how-do-i-install-citrix-ica-client-receiver-13-on-debian-64-bit-linux)

Answer (score 3):

I am answering this question myself because others may find this information useful.  This Q&A was inspired about another one: [How do I install Citrix ICA Client (Receiver) 13 on Debian 64-bit Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/714375/how-do-i-install-citrix-ica-client-receiver-13-on-debian-64-bit-linux)

1. Create a temp directory and copy the `.deb` file to it.
2. Extract the `.deb` file: `ar vx archive.deb`
3. Three files will appear:

   - `debian-binary`: Do not touch
   - `control.tar.gz`: Config and scripts to install and uninstall

     - This file may have a different extension, depending on the compression format used.
   - `data.tar.gz`: Files to be installed

     - This file may have a different extension, depending on the compression format used.

Both `*.tar.gz` files may different extensions, depending on the compression format used.  The `.deb` format supports a few different ones.  Also both `*.tar.gz` files are [tarbombs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29#Tarbomb), so all the files will explode to the same path.  Better to create a temp directory, copy, then extract.

File `control.tar.gz` has two files good for hacking:

- `control`: Contains package dependency list.  You can add/remove dependencies.
- `postinst`: Contains the post-installation script.  You can add/remove commands.

Recreate the `*.tar.gz` files as: `tar -czvf control.tar.gz *` or (`data.tar.gz`)

Finally, create a new archive.  Order is very important here: `ar rv my_new_package.deb debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz`

You can try your new package with these commands:

- Uninstall existing package: `apt-get remove $package_name`

  - ... where `$package_name` is the name of your package, e.g., `icaclient`
- Install new package: `dpkg --install my_new_package.deb`

Ref: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/

Comment: Just to add some extra info, note that the deb format is *not* actually identical to the `ar` format. If you manually pack debs in that way, `dpkg` will usually be fine with it, but some other important tools such as `apt-ftparchive` will not. Where available, you'll be better off unpacking with `dpkg-deb -R mypkg.deb tempdir` and re-packing with `dpkg-deb -b tempdir`.